# What does virtual core in YARN vcore mean?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Yarn is using the concept of virtual core to manage CPU resources. I would ask what's the benefit to use virtual core, is there some reason here that YARN uses vcore?

Answer (score 5):

Here is what the documentation states (emphasis mine)

> A node's capacity should be configured with virtual cores equal to its
>   number of physical cores. A container should be requested with the
>   number of cores it can saturate, i.e. the average number of threads it
>   **expects to have runnable** at a time.

Unless the CPU core is hyper-threaded  it can run only one thread at a time (in case of hyper threaded OS actually sees 2 cores for one physical core and can run two threads - of course it's a bit of cheating and no-where as efficient as having actual physical core). Essentially what it means to end user is that a core can run a single thread so theoretically if I want parallelism using java threads then a reasonably good approximation is number of threads equal to number of core. So if your container process ( which is a JVM)
will require 2 threads then it's better to map it to 2 vcore - that what the last line means. And as total capacity of node the vcore should be equal to number of physical cores.

The most important thing to remember is still that it's actually the OS which will schedule the threads to be executed in different cores as it happens in any other application and
YARN in itself **does not** have control on it except the fact that what is the best possible approximation for how many thread to allocate for each container. And that's why it is important to take into consideration other applications running on OS, CPU cycles used by kernel etc., as all of cores will not be available to YARN application all the time.

**EDIT: Further research**

Yarn does not influence hard limits on CPU but Going through the code I can see how it tries to influence the CPU scheduling or cpu rate. Technically Yarn can launch different container processes - java, python , custom shell command etc. The responsibility of launching containers in Yarn belongs to the ContainerExecutor component of Node manager and I can see code for launching the container etc., along with some hints (depending on platform). For example in case of `DefaultContainerExecutor` ( which extends ContainerExecutor) - for windows it uses "-c" parameter for cpu restriction and on linux it uses process niceness to influence it. There is another implementation `LinuxContainerExecutor` (or better still `CgroupsLCEResourcesHandler` as former does not force the usage of cgroups) which tries to use Linux cgroups to limit the Yarn CPU resources on that node. More details can be found [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeManagerCgroups.html).

```
ContainerExecutor {
.......
.......

 protected String[] getRunCommand(String command, String groupId,
      String userName, Path pidFile, Configuration conf, Resource resource) {
    boolean containerSchedPriorityIsSet = false;
    int containerSchedPriorityAdjustment = 
        YarnConfiguration.DEFAULT_NM_CONTAINER_EXECUTOR_SCHED_PRIORITY;

    if (conf.get(YarnConfiguration.NM_CONTAINER_EXECUTOR_SCHED_PRIORITY) != 
        null) {
      containerSchedPriorityIsSet = true;
      containerSchedPriorityAdjustment = conf 
          .getInt(YarnConfiguration.NM_CONTAINER_EXECUTOR_SCHED_PRIORITY, 
          YarnConfiguration.DEFAULT_NM_CONTAINER_EXECUTOR_SCHED_PRIORITY);
    }

    if (Shell.WINDOWS) {
      int cpuRate = -1;
      int memory = -1;
      if (resource != null) {
        if (conf
            .getBoolean(
                YarnConfiguration.NM_WINDOWS_CONTAINER_MEMORY_LIMIT_ENABLED,
                YarnConfiguration.DEFAULT_NM_WINDOWS_CONTAINER_MEMORY_LIMIT_ENABLED)) {
          memory = resource.getMemory();
        }

        if (conf.getBoolean(
            YarnConfiguration.NM_WINDOWS_CONTAINER_CPU_LIMIT_ENABLED,
            YarnConfiguration.DEFAULT_NM_WINDOWS_CONTAINER_CPU_LIMIT_ENABLED)) {
          int containerVCores = resource.getVirtualCores();
          int nodeVCores = conf.getInt(YarnConfiguration.NM_VCORES,
              YarnConfiguration.DEFAULT_NM_VCORES);
          // cap overall usage to the number of cores allocated to YARN
          int nodeCpuPercentage = Math
              .min(
                  conf.getInt(
                      YarnConfiguration.NM_RESOURCE_PERCENTAGE_PHYSICAL_CPU_LIMIT,
                      YarnConfiguration.DEFAULT_NM_RESOURCE_PERCENTAGE_PHYSICAL_CPU_LIMIT),
                  100);
          nodeCpuPercentage = Math.max(0, nodeCpuPercentage);
          if (nodeCpuPercentage == 0) {
            String message = "Illegal value for "
                + YarnConfiguration.NM_RESOURCE_PERCENTAGE_PHYSICAL_CPU_LIMIT
                + ". Value cannot be less than or equal to 0.";
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
          }
          float yarnVCores = (nodeCpuPercentage * nodeVCores) / 100.0f;
          // CPU should be set to a percentage * 100, e.g. 20% cpu rate limit
          // should be set as 20 * 100. The following setting is equal to:
          // 100 * (100 * (vcores / Total # of cores allocated to YARN))
          cpuRate = Math.min(10000,
              (int) ((containerVCores * 10000) / yarnVCores));
        }
      }
      return new String[] { Shell.WINUTILS, "task", "create", "-m",
          String.valueOf(memory), "-c", String.valueOf(cpuRate), groupId,
          "cmd /c " + command };
    } else {
      List<String> retCommand = new ArrayList<String>();
      if (containerSchedPriorityIsSet) {
        retCommand.addAll(Arrays.asList("nice", "-n",
            Integer.toString(containerSchedPriorityAdjustment)));
      }
      retCommand.addAll(Arrays.asList("bash", command));
      return retCommand.toArray(new String[retCommand.size()]);
    }

  }
      }
```

For windows (it utilizes winutils.exe) , it uses cpu rate 
For Linux it uses niceness as a parameter to control the CPU priority

Answer (score 3):

"Virtual cores" are merely an abstraction of actual cores. This abstraction or "lie" (as i like to call it), allows YARN (and others) to dynamically spin threads (parallel process) based on availability. Take for example running map reduce on an "elastic" cluster with a processing limit constrained only by your wallet... The cloud baby... The. Cloud.

you can read more [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/ey-setup.html)

Comment: Thanks @archae0pteryx.